# Where does it say it’s not about the job but rather it’s the merits?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, torah-study, midrash, derech-eretz-manners

BH

I heard that it's not about the Job or certain profession that you have rather it's your merits that actually bring you your parnasa if this is an accurate statement according to the Talmud what is the source?

Answer (score 6):

[Kiddushin 82a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.82a.6?lang=bi):

> רבי מאיר אומר: לעולם ילמד אדם את בנו אומנות נקיה וקלה, ויתפלל למי שהעושר והנכסים שלו. שאין אומנות שאין בה עניות ועשירות, שלא עניות מן האומנות, ולא עשירות מן האומנות, אלא הכל לפי זכותו.
>
> Rabbi Meir says: A person should always teach his son a clean and easy trade and pray for success to the One to Whom wealth and property belong, as ultimately there is no trade that does not include both poverty and wealth, since a person can become rich from any profession. Poverty does not come from a particular trade, nor does wealth come from a particular trade, but rather, all is in accordance with a person’s merit.